# Gnuplot: line not recognised

Tags: gnuplot, linestyle

I am trying to change the line style of my gnuplot graph (there is only one line, I have only a simple plot of y versus x)
However, when I type:
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' ... (or linewidth or whatever argument)
(& replot)
nothing happens... it seems that it doesn't recognise the plot as "line 1".. I also tried to change the line index to a different number or its name...

Could anybody please help what to put "set style ..." argument?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Gnuplot has `linestyle` and `linetype`:

```
set linetype 1 linecolor "yellow"
plot x
```

or

```
set style line 1 linecolor "magenta"
plot x linestyle 1
```

Using `set linetype` is the recommended way, line style is deprecated.

Note, that resetting the line type must be done with `reset session` (gnuplot version 5), `reset` alone doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks so much for your answer. However it does not work...
When I use "set linetype 1 linecolor....", gnuplot complains "Unrecognized option.  See 'help set'. " ... :(   "set style line 1 linecolor "magenta" ! is what I did before, nothing happens to the plot. I get the feeling that the number 1 (in "line 1") might be the problem... but having only one line should be 1, shouldn't it?

Comment: Which gnuplot version do you have? `set linetype` works since 4.6. And regarding the linestyle: important is the plot command, where I explicitly select a *style* for plotting.

Comment: Ok, thanks this might explain the problem then !!! :) I have version 4.4